# How to play a video being downloaded as if it was a stream?

Tags: python, video, google-drive-api, html5-video, chromecast

I'm using Google Drive's API to download a video from my Drive account. However, I'm using Partial Download, receiving the file by chunks. This is done by a Python script.

If I try to play it using html5 , it won't work as I want because it plays until the size the file had before loading the page and then it stops, without waiting for the next chunk or updating to the current filesize.

Is there a way to play it as if it was streaming?

In the near future I also need to stream this way to chromecast and other devices (android, ps4, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is called progressive download, or pseudo-streaming. It is possible with the mp4 container if the moov atom is before the mdat atom. This is sometimes called faststart